# Print (decrypt) a vim encrypted file

Tags: vim, encryption, printing, cat, decryption

I use the `-x` option in vim to encrypt a file. I read this files much more times than I write to it, so I always use cat and then remember it is encrypted because of what it shows.. So then I have to use vim, enter the password and then exit using `:q` ..

Is there any way to use cat (or another command, of course passing my password somewhere) and just print/get the contents? Or maybe is there just a vim option that only prints the contents without entering the editor?

Comment: There's a shell script bundled with Vim that sets it up to behave similarly to the less pager. It's located in "$VIMRUNTIME/macros/less.sh" and uses the "$VIMRUNTIME/macros/less.vim" script. See `:help less`. Unfortunately it does still require pressing `q` (no `:` needed) to exit.

Comment: Try the open-source [vimdecrypt](https://github.com/gertjanvanzwieten/vimdecrypt).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the open-source [vimdecrypt](https://github.com/gertjanvanzwieten/vimdecrypt) :

> Command line tool for decrypting vim-blowfish-encrypted files.
>
> As of version 7.3 vim offers strong built in blowfish
>   encryption/decryption, which for certain purposes is more convenient
>   than filtering through gnupg. Unfortunately the resulting files can
>   only be read back by vim which makes it hard to use them in batch
>   processing or scripting. Also longevity of encrypted data is a concern
>   if a program with the dependencies and size of vim is required to
>   unlock it.
>
> Vimdecrypt lifts two relevant files from the vim source, blowfish.c
>   and sha256.c, and interfaces them in a simple command line tool. Data
>   is read from a file, decrypted data is written to stdout.
>
> ```
> vimdecrypt path_to_data
> ```
>
> The password is obtained via GNU getpass which does not interfere with
>   stdin/stdout redirection.
>
> Vim's configure system is entirely stripped away which might have
>   broken support for other platforms than the 32 bit i386 linux it was
>   developed on. Since the two relevant files are taken from the vim
>   project unmodified it should be trivial to restore support on other
>   platforms by fixing the vim.h header.

Comment: I have tried it but it throws me "input should be a vim-encrypted file". I think that maybe does not support newer versions  or vim or maybe its a problem of the encryption method being used in my file?

Comment: I see that the magics declared in that script are `magics = None, b'VimCrypt~02!', b'VimCrypt~03!'` and I checked my file and it starts with `VimCrypt~01!` :(

Comment: VimCrypt 01 is PZKIP crypt rather than blowfish/blowfish2. Could build something similar by grabbing crypt_zip.c from vim distro and adding support in vimdecrypt.c for calling crypt_zip_init and crypt_zip_encode instead of the blowfish variants. I'm ALMOST tempted to do this myself.

Comment: You are using the old pkzip based encryption (which is broken, but still the default for compatibility reasons) and not the new (as of Vim 7.3) blowfish based system. I know that blowfish is VimCrypt~02 and I suppose that blowfish2 is VimCrypt~03. You could convert your encryption to the stronger blowfish or blowfish2, as [described here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Encryption), and then vimdecrypt will probably work for you.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks! it worked perfectly. Here's your bounty.

Answer (score 6):

This is not an elegant solution---it is quick and dirty---but it does work on single files and you can use it as a shell script.

It's a sequence of three commands which perform the following:

1. Open file in vim (read only mode): `vim -R`
2. Save the file in plaintext and quit: `-c ":set key= | sav ${filename}.plain | q`
3. Cat the plaintext file: `cat ${filename}.plain`
4. (Optionally) delete the plaintext file: `rm ${filename}.plain`

In the end you can have a script that also passes the password to the vim command. As a simple script it would be:

```
filename=$1
password=$2

vim -R -c ":set key= | sav ${filename}.plain | q" -- ${filename} <<< $password && cat ${filename}.plain && rm ${filename}.plain
```

where the first argument is the filename and the second is the password.

Of course, there are several things you should keep in mind:

- Make sure you're not overwriting existing files which happen to have the name `${filename}.plain`.
- The password will appear on the command line and be saved in history. If you want to be prompted for a password every time, remove the `<<< $password` part.